# Spring expression not working after upgrading from spring 4.1.1 to 4.3.3

Tags: spring

We would like to upgrade from spring 4.1.1 to 4.3.3 but have a problem with some spring expressions in our xml which work in 4.1.1 but not in the later versions.

We create a variable within the evaluation context as below:

```
evaluationContextAccessor.getEvalContext().setVariable("report", report)
```

Then in an xml configuration file we have a prototype scoped bean with:

```
<property name="resource" value="#{#report.artifact}"/>
```

Where artifact in the report object is a Resource

The exception we get after the upgrade is:

```
failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'artifact' cannot be found on null
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.event.ReportCompletedAdaptor.onApplicationEvent(ReportCompletedAdaptor.java:34)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.event.ReportCompletedAdaptor.onApplicationEvent(ReportCompletedAdaptor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.ReportRunner.fireReportCompletedEvent(ReportRunner.java:364)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.ReportRunner.doEvent(ReportRunner.java:347)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.ReportRunner.generateReport(ReportRunner.java:252)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.ReportRunner.generateReport(ReportRunner.java:211)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.ReportRunner.createReport(ReportRunner.java:195)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.MultiReportRunner.processReport(MultiReportRunner.java:88)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.MultiReportRunner.run(MultiReportRunner.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.run(Unknown Source)
    at uk.org.ppa.dispatcherapplications.AbstractRunnerWithPeriodTypeParameter.main(AbstractRunnerWithPeriodTypeParameter.java:119)
```

When debugging it does appear that the evaluation context does include the report object as variable

I presume soemthing must've changed after 4.1.1

Any ideas would be gratefully received

Comment: `="#{#report.artifact}` must be `="#{report.artifact}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately that produces a different exception probably because report is a variable, exception is Property or field 'report' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Looks like Report is null

Comment: It certainly does, but in debug the evaluation context does does contain teh reprot object and it works in spring 4.1.1, so I assume something has changed between the versions